# Where do LAX commercial cargo planes land/take off?

Tags: runways, klax

At the Los Angeles airport, do commercial freight planes such as a 777F, 737F etc. take off near the Lufthansa / FedEx / DHL cargo areas from the 25L /25R runways towards the ocean ?

Do they land in the same direction but farther down the runway?

Comment: They takeoff and land into the wind, just like any other plane.  They can takeoff and land with a tailwind, but it can't be a very strong wind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't operated out of LAX for some time, however, from the early 80's to the mid 90's LAX operated with some generally predictable patterns. Freight carriers were handled in the same way as all other carriers. Takeoffs were USUALLY conducted from 25R and 24L (Inner Pair). Landings USUALLY conducted form 25L and 24R (Outer Pair). During weather with significant wind from the West TO's 6R & 7L / Landings 6L & 7R. Late at night during normal op with minimal wind from the West the 6's and 7's would be used for landings to mitigate noise over the city.

Answer (score 11):

Large airports like LAX see hundreds of planes departing or arriving every day. They manage traffic flow in the entire area (class Bravo airspace) to optimize their traffic. Cargo aircraft will be treated just like any other aircraft. Which runways are in use for departures and which ones for arrivals, depends on the current winds and preferred configurations of the airport. Due to the high traffic, the airport will not deviate from this configuration to accommodate a single cargo aircraft, which would then be closer to its cargo area. Cargo aircraft will then taxi to their respective cargo areas just like passenger aircraft taxi to their gate on the ground.